# how to execute frequently run bash commands with less keystrokes?

Tags: vim

I'm frequently running the following bash command from within vim:

```
! cordova emulate
```

What are my options for reducing the number of keystrokes?  Please describe how to implement as well.

Note that I'd prefer NOT to create a bash alias for this command.

Comment: Create a vim shortcut?

Comment: Thanks @EverythingRightPlace.  I've updated the question slightly to ask not just for the options, but how to implement them (I'm still a vim noob).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash aliases don't work in Vim by default anyway.

You could add this mapping in `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <F5> :!cordova emulate<CR>
```